Android application backup software that covers as much data/settings as possible
I'm looking for Android backup software that tries to backup and then restore as much application data/settings as possible, and nothing else:

any sort of app data
notification settings
permissions
accessibility settings

etc.
It can:

require root
require the same Android version or even the same OS and version, although bonus if it doesn't
be premium or freemium

I'm 99.99% nothing like this exists as of now, but maybe some day someone will ping me with an answer.

As adb backup does no longer work for recent apps on Android 12+ there is no way to get app data on a non-rooted device. Thus the only apps that remain are the migration tools provided by Google respectively by the different phone manufacturer.

As the question specifies, rooting is fine. Also solutions for any relatively modern versions are fine, it doesn't have to cover 12+ specifically.

Must the application run on the Android device itself? Then I'd suggest to take a look at NeoBackup. For use with ADB from a computer, you might wish to check my Adebar (with the root options enabled). Both cover app data. None cover all your criteria fully, as you already suspected. Should these two (or one of them) be an acceptable solution please let me know, and I'll see to write up an answer.

Thanks. Doesn't matter where they run, as long as they cover all or at least most of the data/settings. I heardabout NeoBackupand I think it only covers app data, let me know if I'm wrong. I'll check out Adebar.
